# ReSharper : "Condition is always false" warning when reading value from ViewBag in .jQuery

Tags: jquery, resharper

I am assigning some value to `ViewBag` in the controller and reading it in `jQuery` in `View`. I can see the value but when I am adding some condition, `ReSharper` always shows `Condition is always 'false'` warning. Why is that?

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ViewQueue(int? id)
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.ConceptId = id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error");
        throw new Exception("Error occured, Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

View:

```
$(function () {
    $('a[id="CancelJob"]').click(function (event) {

    var conceptId = '@ViewBag.ConceptId';

    alert("conceptId " + conceptId); // Getting id here.

    if (conceptId == null) { // Seeing warning here.
        // TODO: Get conceptId from somewhere else if conceptId is null or undefined.
    }
});
```

I have tried following as well but same result:

```
   // using identity operator
    if (conceptId === null) {
    }

    // Checking 'truthy'
    if (conceptId) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that you're mixing your `null` concepts. `Null` on the server is not the same as `null` on the client. Or, `null` from **C#** is not the same as `null` on **Javascript**.

Let me explain myself a little:

Looking at your action's signature: `public ActionResult ViewQueue(int? id)`, if you don't pass the id on the route, it will be set to null, thanks to **default parameters feature** that C# 4.0 got back in 2010 and enables this interesting scenario for ASP.NET MVC.

Let's say we pass an id on the first call:

```
http://localhost:12345/Ctrl/ViewQueue/5
```

If you inspect the code that gets generated on the client using Chrome Developer Tools for instance, you'll see that the line of code where you assigned the `conceptId` variable:

`var conceptId = '@ViewBag.ConceptId';`

It has been translated now to something like this on the client:

`var conceptId = '5';`.

The expression got evaluated on the server side during the razor view rendering and the value for conceptId was assigned ok.

So far, so good.

Let's try now without the parameter. We call http://localhost:12345/Ctrl/ViewQueue thus leaving the parameter to be set to null.

If you inspect again the generated code for your view, you'll see something interesting:

```
var conceptId = '';
```

Your line has now been translated to an empty string assignment, and that's what **Reshaper** is telling you: there is no way this will be `null`. Ever.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So that means, I have to check for `' '` instead of `null`. Like this, `if (!conceptId .trim()) {
    // is empty or whitespace
} `

Comment: Let me try that and see what happens. Thank you very much for thorough explanation.